# How can I store only one object into array in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Why doesn't the below code store one object into the array? I can't find my mistake. If the array has one object already, it should display another message.
Here is the C# code. I guess the XAML code isn't necessary. Perhaps my mistake is with NULL?

```
 TraderInfos[] bossArray = new TraderInfos[1];

        public Reset_Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }




        private void CheckPassword(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (bossArray != null)
            {

                if (SecurtyQuestionMother.Text == securityQ_mother_textbox.Text  && SecurityQuestionSchool.Text == securityQ_school_texbox.Text) 
                {

                    foreach (var item in bossArray)
                    {
                        PasswordApears.Text = $"Your password is: {item.Password}";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PasswordApears.Text = "You've not found it";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There isnt being any data stored yet");
            }
        }

        private void SafeTheEntries(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (bossArray == null)

            {
                TraderInfos boss = new TraderInfos()
                {
                    First_Name = first_name_textbox.Text,
                    Last_Name = last_name_textbox.Text,
                    Company_Name = company_name_textbox.Text,
                    Phonenumber = phonenumber_textbox.Text,
                    Password = passwordText.Text,
                    SecurityQuestionMother = securityQ_mother_textbox.Text,
                    SecurityQuestionSchool = securityQ_school_texbox.Text
                };

                bossArray[0] = boss;

                MessageBox.Show($"dear {boss.First_Name}!\nYour data has been saved!");

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can't enter more one entry!");

            }

        }
```

Comment: Using an array like this is pointless. Just use `TraderInfos boss;` instead and check `if (boss != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates the array at the top and, because of that, your array will not be null.  The `bossArray[0]` should be equal to `null`, not `bossArray`.

So check

```
if (bossArray[0] != null)
```

or

```
if (bossArray[0] == null)
```

Comment: hey Brett, thanks alot! it solved the problem!! but, when i add second object, the right message appears but deletes the first object! because for the password recovery, says "There isnt any object stored" after second object entry! would give me any idea, please?

Comment: The `bossArray` is initialized to `new TraderInfos[1]` so there can only ever be 1 item in `bossArray`.  You should rethink what the intention of `bossArray` is and see if a better collection type exists (i.e. `List<TraderInfos>,` `HashTable`, etc.)

Comment: thanks!! yeah, i want only one object into the array, therefore no need for other collection, i guess! the at the moment, the problem is only, why does it delete first object after the second object entry, i didnt get your explanation.

Comment: When you used `new TraderInfos[1]`, the the `1` is the size of the array.  The array cannot hold any more `TraderInfos` objects in it.  So when you put `bossArray[0] = boss;`, it overwrites the entry in `bossArray[0]`.  Does that help explain it?

Comment: Awesome! thanks alot. could be any simple solution for avoiding the overwriting?

Comment: If you want to avoid the overwriting, you must want to keep the original input info.  If that is the case, I would suggest creating a `List<TraderInfos> bossList = new List<TraderInfos>()` and instead of `bossArray[0] = boss;`, you use `bossList.Add(boss);`   If you have no reason to keep the original input info, just leave the code as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211897/discussion-between-brett-wertz-and-naseer-akbari).